# Reasons for Magento redirecting to an install page

Tags: magento-1, redirect, installation

I have cloned a git repository containing a magento site in the same way as I normally do when joining a project. I went through the usual process of setting up database and setting everything up on my local.

This time for some reason everytime I try to view the site through my browser it redirects to the magento install page. I have only set up a few magento sites in the past and none were from scratch but I assume due to not having to install it before, I shouldn't have to this time. Any ideas what may be wrong or what file I need to modify to get this to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The chief cause of this is a missing or misnamed `local.xml` file in `app/etc/` - this file is responsible for database connection details and cache settings. If it is missing it is assumed that it is a new installation and prompts you through the installation routine.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the answer. What you suggested definitely fixed one problem but for some reason now every page says - There has been an error processing your request. If you could point me in the right direction it would be a great help. Thanks again..

Comment: In many cases this is because the defined database user does not have permission to read/update the database as configured. There is likely an error # issued on that screen, there should be a corresponding log # in your mage install `var/report/` folder or check in the general php error log. Best of luck.

Comment: @ThomasRyan The "There has been an error processing your request." error page usually contains a reference number. This reference points you to a text file under var/reports with more information on the error.  It is likely unrelated to this question so if you can't resolve it yourself please create a new question.

Comment: @philwinkle sounds good thank you very much.

Comment: @fooman I just noticed this and am looking into it now. Thanks for the advice

Comment: even if app/etc/local.xml is present, the content may be wrong or corrupt in some way. make sure all the node contents look correct and the document is valid xml.

Comment: This can also happen if the permissions on the local.xml file are incorrect or the app/etc/local.xml file is a link to a local.xml file with incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly there are two reasons if you are getting installation page:

`app/etc/local.xml` file is missing or this file has wrong or unfinished syntax.

Answer (score 0):

wrong permissions. i had this problem when updated core files under root. fixed the problem by running in magento folder:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ./*
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to above answers there is a possibility of missing file while doing migration.
Rename your downloader directory to something else and refresh the page it will start showing the missing file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux servers and fresh installation of Magento just change ownership of folder. 
Sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /{Dir}

Answer (score 0):

Give the `app/etc/local.xml` file 644 permission. If the file exists and still issue is happening.