# website is Redirecting to install.php

Tags: magento-1.9

Moved website from Live server to Local wamp server and when I try to access the website on local server it is prompting me to install magento again

I mean when I type `http://localhost/mywebsite/`  it is going to install page at `http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php/install/` instead of showing front end of the website ..

The problem doesn't seems to replicate on live server, I have uploaded same copy of files and database on live server again and it works fine . I am using, must be something with the wamp server settings

What could be the issue...

Thanks

Comment: you changed database of live server to local ?

Comment: i am installing a copy of live website on my local server, after copying files and uploading database file on local server and changing database name, password and user  in local.xml file , I deleted the cache and session folders and after that when try to access my local file it goes to  "http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php/install/"  I have changed the base url in the core_config_data..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reasons for Magento redirecting to an install page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9401/reasons-for-magento-redirecting-to-an-install-page)

Answer (score 2):

You will be prompted to install if `app/etc/local.xml` is missing.  Make sure this exists and contains database connection details.

Comment: it is available in etc folder.. is it something to do with sample data... the website has magneto sample data in it..

Comment: i think it is finding local.xml when I put wrong database name, it gives me error, when database is right it takes me to installation page .

Comment: Something else must at play here then, as such I would tend to agree with the voters above - the potential causes are too broad to easily be determined and resolved here.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with sample data. Your `app/etc/local.xml` is incorrect. Check the file path, file name, and the content. I suggest getting a new copy from a working installation and reconfiguring it.